# FLEX/BISON : Why my rule is not regonized?

Tags: bison, calculator, flex-lexer

I am trying to do a little exercice in FLEX and BISON.

Here is the code I wrote :

**calc_pol.y**

```
%{
#define YYSTYPE double
#include "calc_pol.tab.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
%}
%start line
%token NOMBRE
%token FIN
%%
line: exp '\n' { printf("\t%.2lf\n", $1); };
exp: exp exp '+' { $$ = $1 + $2 ;}
     | exp exp '-' { $$ = $1 - $2 ;}
     | exp exp '*' { $$ = $1 * $2 ;}
     | exp exp '/' { $$ = $1 / $2 ;}
     | exp exp '^' { $$ = pow($1, $2) ;}
     | NOMBRE;
%%
```

**calc_pol.l**

```
%{
    #include "calc_pol.tab.h"
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    extern YYSTYPE yylval;
%}

blancs  [ \t]+

chiffre [0-9]
entier  [+-]?[1-9][0-9]* | 0
reel    {entier}('.'{entier})?

%%

{blancs} 
{reel}  { yylval = atof(yytext); return NOMBRE; }
\n      { return FIN; }
.       { return yytext[0]; }
%%
```

**Makefile**

```
all: calc_pol.tab.c lex.yy.c
        gcc -o calc_pol $< -ly -lfl -lm

calc_pol.tab.c: calc_pol.y
        bison -d calc_pol.y

lex.yy.c: calc_pol.l
        flex calc_pol.l
```

Do you have any idea of what's wrong ?
Thanks

Edited:
The error message is
`flex calc_pol.l: calc_pol.l:18: règle non reconnue`
Line 18 is the line beginning with `{reel}`, and the error message translates to English as "unrecognized rule".

Comment: To answer the question, no I don't have any idea of what's wrong.  Do you have any actual evidence that something is going wrong?  Such as diagnostic output, or test results from calc_pol?

Comment: `flex calc_pol.l`: calc_pol.l:18: règle non reconnue

Comment: Which is line 18?  In a comment below, you identify it as `{reel}  { yylval = atof(yytext); return NOMBRE; }`; is that correct?  Also, Google tells me that the error message translates to "unrecognized rule".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem came from the space between `|` in the `entier` rules

Answer (score 6):

I don't want to break pleasure of flash of inspiration, that is why only hint: what the difference between

```
1 2
```

and

```
12
```

Comment: 1 and 2 are two operand then 12 is only one. I don't get your point.

Comment: +1 because this should have been credit for the answer, not his OWN answer :)

Answer (score 0):

in **calc_pol.l**

```
{blancs} { ; } <------- !!
{reel}  { yylval = atof(yytext); return NOMBRE; }
\n      { return FIN; }
.       { return yytext[0]; }
```

I would be inclined to spot that you're missing an action for the '{blancs}'...

**Edit:** As more information came out of the OP the problem....is here....

```
entier  [+-]?[1-9][0-9]+
reel    {entier}('.'{entier})?
```

I would take out the last bit at the end of 'entier' as it looks to be a greedy match and hence not see the real number like '123.234'...what do you think?

Comment: It is just to notice to flex that in case of blank, we don't want to do anything.

The problem comes from the {reel} line.

Comment: 0 is also an integer. I just don't want some integer like 0000 but this rule seams good for me. Anyway, it doesn't change the error.

Comment: @Natim: the ('.'{entier})? means zero or 1, so it should accept an integer....test cases would be -23, 23, 23.45, -123.34, 123.34....

Comment: The definition using entier after the . is wrong you are right. I changed like this `reel    {entier}('.'[0-9]+)?`